# twitter-typeahead not autocompleting or selecting

Tags: twitter-typeahead

Getting some weird behaviour with Twitter typeahead. It correctly fetches the data and displays a drowndown list after 3 characters are input, but it does NOT autocomplete the field, nor highlight/select the item. What have I done wrong?

[image: screenshot]

I have the following javascript (after all the relevant jquery and typeahead stuff):

```
$(function ()
{

    var customers = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        remote: {
            url: '/api/customers?query=%QUERY',
            wildcard: '%QUERY'
        }
    });

    $('#customer').typeahead
    (
        {
            minLength: 3,
            highlight: true
        },
        {
            name: 'customers',
            display: 'name',
            source: customers
        }
    );


});
```

relevant part of the webpage

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Customer</label>
        <input id="customer" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Movie</label>
        <input id="movie" type="text" value="" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

And the css:

```
.typeahead {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}

.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}

.tt-menu {
  width: 422px;
  margin: 12px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
     -moz-border-radius: 8px;
          border-radius: 8px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
          box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

It seems to get rendered out as:

```
<input id="customer" type="text" value="" class="form-control tt-input" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" dir="auto" style="position: relative; vertical-align: top; background-color: transparent;">
```

Which is interesting, as it says

```
autocomplete="off"
```

but changing that doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my controller was returning an `IHttpActionResult` rather than the `IEnumerable<Customer>` that I was expecting. I don't KNOW if that was the issue, but now that I have fixed that, it works..